# How to force ListView manually recreate view using its .Items.Filter?

Tags: wpf, listview, filter

I got a `ListView` with an `ItemsSource` collection, where `ObservableCollection<string>` is set.
And, the `ListView` contains a filter in its `ListView.Items.Filter` property (as a `Predicate<bool,object>`.

So let's say there are conditions when the filter can change its behavior without changing its own reference.

And when those conditions change i need to let the `ListView` know that it has to reconstruct its view according to the new filter.

The only solution i've figured is

```
ListView.Items.Filter = ListView.Items.Filter;
```

which is wrong but it still works. Updates each item again with the filter.

So is there right solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a hold of the collection view (`ICollectionView`) that the `ListView` is bound to and `Refresh()` it. It's not clear to me how you've bound to your data, but you can either:

- Bind to a collection view explicitly
- Bind to a collection and have the control automatically bind to the default collection view

It sounds like you've done the latter, in which case you can use:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(theCollection).Refresh();
```

Comment: I bound it like this: `ListView.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<strnig>(..);`

Comment: Right. Almost forgot that :-[